# Does <meta charset="utf-8" /> do anything?

Tags: html

Does `<meta charset="utf-8" />` do anything or is it just there to let the programmer know that this specific charset is what's being used?

In other words, if i removed this line entirely or forgot to write it in, would utf-8 still be the charset?

Comment: Well done for a first question! Sorry to say it's a duplicate though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does  do anything or is it just there to let
>   the programmer know that this specific charset is what's being used?

It tells the browser what encoding to use to decode the page. The browser needs to use some encoding to turn the byte stream into text, and if you don't specify an encoding, it will come up with an encoding some other way.

> if i removed this line entirely or forgot to write it in, would utf-8
>   still be the charset?

That depends on whether there is a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in the file and what the server sends along in the HTTP header. If you omit the encoding from the page the browser will look for a byte order mark, and if there is none it will look in the header. If there is no encoding specified at all, it will look at the content of the byte stream to make a guess at what encoding it might be.

There is an exact procedure [outlined in the HTML standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#determining-the-character-encoding) for how the browser should try to detect the encoding. Eventhough the steps are specified, exactly how each one is performed is up to the browser. That means that different browsers can actually end up using different encodings if you don't specify it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as it specifies the charset for the document encoding and allows the browser to render such. Different languages have different charsets

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/meta.charset.html

Comment: While the content of w3schools is technically correct, it's so insufficiently detailed as to be a white lie. w3fools was created ages ago to combat how much *awful* information was on w3schools, to the point that it became a meme on SO, and then something to be discouraged when w3schools improved slightly. I still would recommend you avoid referencing w3schools because of how incomplete and insufficient the information is there.

Comment: I agree with your recommendation.